# Angular mat-table - How to bind JSON Object to two different select elements using two-way binding?

Tags: angular, select, html-table, two-way-binding

This is my HTML code:

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="users" class="mat-elevation-z8" color="primary">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="roles">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <span i18n="@@roles">Roles</span>
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user; let i=index;">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select placeholder="User Roles" [(ngModel)]="users[i].roles['code']" multiple>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let role of userRoles" [value]="role.code">
              {{role.desc}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="primaryRole">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <span i18n="@@primaryrole">Primary Role</span>
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user; let i=index;">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select placeholder="Primary Role" [(ngModel)]="users[i].roles['primary']" >
            <mat-option *ngFor="let role of userRoles" [value]="role.primary">
              {{role.desc}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="getTableColumns(); sticky: true;"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: getTableColumns();"></tr>
  </table>
```

Here, 'userRoles' is roles array from master data. 'roles' is array from 'users' data, where, 'users' is outer array and 'roles' is inner array. I want to bind 'code' and 'primary' from roles in two different select elements here. For 'code' select, I can select multiple roles using multiple, but for primary there is single select, but how to bind the object to 'select'?

Comment: can you share your object

Comment: {code: 'role1', desc: 'Role1', primary: false}

Comment: are you getting any error?